# What might it mean to "know" another living being?

Tags: metaphysics, knowledge

Assuming for the moment that life involves change how can one "know" another living being?

Indeed if they are changing can one fully know another living being?

Who has written about knowing in human relationships?

Comment: read Levinas, please

Comment: Life also involves persisting patterns that can be known, and even the change itself can be a fully predetermined appearance. As they say, the more things change the more they stay the same.

Comment: Taking God as an example for knowing a living being seems unfortunate at best. According to process ontologies, there is no static being in the first place. I really think that this question tries to justify something about an alleged entity "God" instead of honestly asking anything about being able to perceive the identity of living beings over time.

Comment: @Philip Kocking Have changed question in view of your comment.

Comment: There Are People Living Inside of You You may think your body and mind are your own. In fact, you are a fusion of many organisms - including, potentially, another person. David Robson, A very large number of different human and non-human individuals are struggling inside us for control https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20150917-is-another-human-living-inside-you In the 1940s, long before the decoding of the human genome, Baebara McClintock realized that some stretches of our DNA behave like infectious invaders. These DNA chunks can move around through the genome, copying and pasting themselve

Comment: This question is too broad because it asks, indirectly, about the nature of knowledge itself regarding the identity of things in flux. This goes back to at least [Heraclitus](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/heraclitus/).

Comment: @ask_hole Levinas’s argument here is that Dasein exists only in dialogue with being. The fundamental encounter for the existent is not with other beings, but with being itself.

Comment: not getting how you're correcting me here @HassanJolany

Answer (score 1):

**From Heidegger's point of view about change and being,**

When being is thought of as change, then it is also coherent to think of temporality or timeliness as underlying the change of beings. A thought which in the everydayness would be understood as time being the factor underlying change. If Heidegger's thought is thought out consequently,then

**the being of beings must be understood as the change of beings.**

Then it must be concluded that

**according to Heidegger's thought, being »is« change**

http://www.arvindus.com/publications/201010201.html

**There is philosophy of "other being" and
the "Constitutive Other being"**

In phenomenology, the terms the Other and the Constitutive Other identify the other human being, in their differences from the Self, as being a cumulative, constituting factor in the self-image of a person; as acknowledgement of being real; hence, the Other is dissimilar to and the opposite of the Self, of Us, and of the Same.

**Hegel introduced the concept of the Other Human being as a constituent part of self-consciousness** (preoccupation with the Self), which complements the propositions about self-awareness (capacity for introspection)

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Other_(philosophy)

**Metaphysical necessity is contrasted with other types of being,**

factual necessity (existential necessity): a factually necessary being is not causally dependent on any other being, while any other being is causally dependent on it.

causal necessity (subsumed by Hicks under the former type): a causally necessary being is such that it is logically impossible for it to be causally dependent on any other being, and it is logically impossible for any other being to be causally independent of it.

logical necessity: a logically necessary being is a being whose non-existence is a logical impossibility, and which therefore exists either timeless or eternally in all possible worlds.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphysical_necessity